# Is there any fully Byobu-compatible terminal client for Windows?

Tags: ssh, putty, byobu, mobaxterm

I'm trying to use Byobu on a Linux server via SSH from Windows.
I've tried with MobaXterm and putty, but some of the F key combinations simply don't work. In MobaXterm there is even a dedicated Byobu terminal type setting, but the F5-F8 keys ignore the key combinations with Ctrl.

I've listed the codes sent to the terminal with `cat -v`. The code for example **F6** is `^[[17~`, but for **Ctrl+F6**, it sends the exact **same** code.

Is there any terminal client for Windows that can send distinct codes for all F-keys with all modifiers (Ctrl, Alt, Shift)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about Windows software

Comment: byobu is a linux software, ssh is a linux technology, and many people are using linux from windows. So I don't think it's totally off-topic. Btw why is there even a putty keyword defined? It is a windows software.

Comment: See if these suggestions help (on PuTTY): https://askubuntu.com/q/529258/819150

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I recomend you `mintty` and `wsltty` and `cmdr` for a quake-like terminal

**Edit:**

My apologies for the previous short answer. `mintty` is a terminal emulator for cygwin that is also used for `git` on windows and as a replacement for the less flexible windows wsl terminal.

In order to get it to work you need to follow the steps bellow after installing mintty :

- Setup the terminal type to `xterm-256color` in the console options
- Disable the scroll bar, since byobu will have its own scroll bar
- Disable all keys modifiers for the keboard and mouse options, so mintty shortcuts don't take interfere with byobu key bindings

Optionally you can:

- Install `cmdr` wich already comes with git for windows and can be used as a dropdown terminal
- In order to copy from byobu to windows you can follow  [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1390516/how-can-i-copy-to-the-system-clipboard-from-byobu)

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank your for your contribution. Perhaps you want to expand your post to include some more instructions on how to combine these for the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

## Terminals running in MS-Windows

You can run various X clients on MS-windows (including terminal emulators), but you will need to run an X11 server on your MS-windows machine: See Cygwin.

## Terminals running remotely, but displayed localy

You can also use VNC, to forward a desktop (does not have to be shared with the real display(screen, keyboard, pointing device) at the remote end).

You can use X11, to forward individual application windows to your local machine: see Cygwin.

## Virtual machines

You can run Gnu/Linux, inside Virtual-Box. This way you can install whatever software you want. It has seamless mode, where windows from host and guest appear together on the same desktop (It works almost seamlessly). On a modern CPU, Virutal-Box is fast.

Comment: MobaXterm contains an X server, so it's not a problem. But for this solution I have to install the GUI packages on the Linux server, right? (I mostly use headless virtual machines via ssh.)

Comment: You can install GUI clients on the Gnu/Linux server, or install them on the local MS-Windows terminal (they can run under Cygwin).

Comment: I've tried to install gnome-terminal and terminator in MobaXterm's internal cygwin, but none of them wants to start for some reason. Then I've tested the "native" bash shell included in Windows 10 (Windows subsystem for Linux) and it seems to work correctly. (Unfortunately I'm using Win 8.1 on my primary machine) If you can add this to the answer, then I will accept it as there are no other suggestions.

Comment: Why not add an answer of you own?